# MySQL combine two tables and order by?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
     WEEKLY                   MONTHLY
|Name|Kills|Deaths|      |Name|Kills|Deaths|
 __________________      __________________
|B   |  1  |  12  |      |B   | 43  |  12  | 
|A   |  3  |  25  |      |A   |  9  |  25  |
|D   |  4  |   2  |      |D   |  8  |   2  | 
|C   |  5  |   4  |      |C   |  5  |   4  |
|F   |  2  |   8  |      |F   | 10  |   8  |
```

I need to retrieve them ordered by the Kill/Death ratio and I believe this is possible to do just with MySQL but things got tricky when i realized i needed to combine the two tables then order the results.

The following works perfectly on 1 table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM weekly ORDER BY kills/deaths DESC;
```

But how can I do this across 2 tables?

Comment: It depends on precisely what you mean by "combine".  Do you want two rows for `A`, one with `kills/deaths` ratio from `WEEKLY` and one with the ratio from `MONTHLY`, or do you want to perform some math operation to combine the numbers?

Comment: Id like to join the kills and deaths from both tables into 1 row per name. Then order them by (kills/deaths).

Comment: By "join", do you mean that you want to add the `Kills` from `WEEKLY` to the `Kills` from `MONTHLY` and then calculate the ratio?

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean.

Comment: Are we sure that a name will be at both tables?

Comment: Yeah the name is the primary key and not null for both.

Comment: I mean if B is in weekly it will be also in monthly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT WEEKLY.Name, WEEKLY.Kills+MONTHLY.Kills Kills, WEEKLY.Deaths+MONTHLY.Deaths Deaths
FROM WEEKLY INNER JOIN MONTHLY ON WEEKLY.Name=MONTHLY.Name
ORDER BY (WEEKLY.Kills+MONTHLY.Kills)/(WEEKLY.Deaths+MONTHLY.Deaths) DESC;
```

Comment: This is returning just the names but in the right order

Comment: its returning the name and kills/deaths twice. but in the right order.

Comment: I think you should add the kills and the deaths for the other two output columns

Comment: @ThatGuy343, Can you tell me precisely what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I just tested JuniorCompressor's and it returned them in right order

Comment: but his didnt combine the kills /deaths

Answer (score 1):

If we need to combine by taking the union of these two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM weekly UNION SELECT * FROM monthly) u
ORDER BY kills / deaths DESC;
```

If we need to combine by adding the kills and deaths for the same name:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, 
    SUM(u.kills) kills, 
    SUM(u.deaths) deaths,
    IFNULL(SUM(u.kills) / SUM(u.deaths), 2147483647) ratio
FROM (SELECT * FROM weekly UNION SELECT * FROM monthly) u
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY ratio DESC, kills DESC;
```

Comment: im getting NULL as the ratio when kills = 2 and deaths = 0. any idea why that is?

Comment: division by zero. What you want at this case?

Comment: perfect thank you, didnt realize mysql could do all this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM weekly a inner join  MONTHLY b
on a.name = b.name
ORDER BY (a.kills+b.kills)/(a.deaths+b.deaths) DESC;
```